# WPF - destroy page after unloaded has run

Tags: wpf, vb.net, navigation

In a WPF app we have the need to sometimes create a new tab that contains a Page inside a Frame..

Once the page has been opened (initialised once) it still seems to stay in navigation history and attempts to load data that may not be relevant at the time.

I have tried a myriad of methods including NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry, but it still persists :-(

This is an example of how the tab/page are opened

```
 Private Sub CashFlow_Edit(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim DGV As DGVx = ReportsCashFlow_Grid.FindName("CashFlow_DGV")
        e.Handled = True
        IsNewRecord = False

        If DGV.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
            Dim row As System.Data.DataRowView = DGV.SelectedItems(0)
            Form_ID = row("ID")
            Dim vName As String = row("Name")
            Dim vTab As STC_Tabx = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName(TabName)
            Dim TabControl As STCx = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("AccountingReports_TabControl")
            If Not vTab Is Nothing Then
                vTab.Close()
            End If
            Dim MCFrame As New Frame
            Dim MCTab As New STC_Tabx
            With MCTab
                .Name = TabName
                .Header = " " & vName & " "
                .ImageSource = ReturnImageAsString("Edit.png", 16)
                .CloseButtonVisibility = DevComponents.WpfEditors.eTabCloseButtonVisibility.Visible
                .TabToolTip = "View or edit the " & vName & " template"
                .Content = MCFrame
            End With
            RemoveHandler MCTab.Closing, AddressOf TabControl_TabClosing
            AddHandler MCTab.Closing, AddressOf TabControl_TabClosing

            Dim vGrid As Grid = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("MainGrid_Accounting")
            RegisterControl(vGrid, MCTab)
            TabControl.Items.Add(MCTab)
            Dim MCPage As New ReportCashFlow_Page
            MCFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(MCPage)
            LoadedTabs(TabName)
            MCTab.IsSelected = True


        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the clean bit of code I would like, but it works - create a global Boolean  - when the sub that opens the tab/page is called it's set to true and the loading event will only run the loading code if this is true - it's set to false at the end.

```
Private Sub ReportCashFlow_Page_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Try


        If IsNewTab = False Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
 'Run all the loading code here


  Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    Finally
        IsNewTab = False
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, CType(Sub() CashFlow_LoadBudget(), SendOrPostCallback), Nothing)
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, CType(Sub() ToggleReserve(), SendOrPostCallback), Nothing)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all the back entries do something like:

```
while(NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

Comment: Tried that - has no effect